# How does linkage and name mangling work?

Tags: c++, linker, declaration

Lets take this code sample

```
//header
struct A { };
struct B { };
struct C { };
extern C c;

//code
A myfunc(B&b){ A a; return a; }
void myfunc(B&b, C&c){}
C c;
```

Lets do this line by line starting from the code section.
When the compiler sees the first myfunc method it does not care about A or B because its use is internal. Each c++ file will know what it takes in, what it returns. Although there needs to be a name for each of the two overload so how is that chosen and how does the linker know which means what?
Next is C c; I once had a bug were the linker wouldnt reconize thus allow me access to C in other C++ files. It was because that cpp didnt know c was extern and i had to mark it as extern in the header before i could link successfully. Now i am not sure if the class type has any involvement with the linker and the variable C. I dont know how RTTI will be involved but i do know C needs to be visible by other files.

How does the linker work and name mangling and such.

Comment: @Tom: I dont remember but i am positive the C++ standard doesnt enforce making non extern variable visible to other files. But then again it isnt static either

Comment: Your questions aren't very clear. "When the compiler sees the first myfunc method[,] it does not care about A or B because its use is internal."  Actually, it cares about B for the purposes of name mangling myfunc.  Could you clarify what you're trying to say (and ask)?

Comment: @Adrian: It might care but it doesnt need to use the parameter names as part of the mangled name. I'm trying to ask with the data that needs to be shared with other object files how does the linker match up the objects (the header files could be different and definitely likely have different defines such as debug and release.

Comment: @acidzombie: Right, it doesn't care about the parameter names, but it does care about the parameter types.  I see you've selected an answer, but I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @Adrian: It turns out the elf manual didnt have that info. A better question is how does two .cpp files and the linker know which overload match up with the .cpp files dont have the same information (ex: two 15letter classes with a letter difference but same struct size, why doesnt the name collide)

Comment: Information on name mangling (and other ABI related issues) for the Itanuim (and also ARM) platforms can be found at: http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling

Answer (score 3):

We first need to understand where compilation ends and linking begins. Compilation involves taking a compilation unit (a C or C++ source file) and turning it into an object file. Simplistically, this involves generating snippets of machine code for each function as well as a symbol table for all functions and static (global) variables. Placeholders are used for any symbols needed by the compilation unit that are external to the said compilation unit.

The linker is then responsible for loading all the object files and resolving all the place-holder symbols with real addresses (or offsets for machine independent code). This is placed into various sections that can be read by the operating system's dynamic loader when loading an executable.

So for the specifics. In order to avoid errors during linking, the compiler requires you to declare all external symbols that will be used by the current compilation unit. For global variables one must use the `extern` keyword, for functions this is optional.

All functions and global variables defined in a compilation unit have external linkage (i.e., can be referenced by other compilation units) unless one declares that with the `static` keyword (or the unnamed namespace in C++). In C++, the vtable will also have a symbol needed for linkage.

Now in C++, since functions can be overloaded, the parameters also form part of the function name. Since machine-code is just addresses and registers, extra information needs to be added to the function name in the symbols table. This extra parameter information comes in the form of a mangled name and ensures that the linker links to the correct version of an overloaded function.

If you really are interested in the gory details take a look at the [ELF file format (PDF)](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) used extensively on Linux. Windows has a different format but the principles can be expected to be  the same.
Name mangling on the Itanuim (and ARM) platforms can be found [here](http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling).

Comment: I jumped the gun. I saw symbol table and mention of external libs/dynamic loading but i didnt see anything talking about how to find/match up names

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: hmm, i didnt -1. I'll mention that wikipedia makes no mention of variable naming or other things that make be visible to other compiled files

Comment: I did. This is not an answer.